# I have questions regarding SQL queries using joins

Tags: mysql

Query that display all Students name, with their gender, father name and mother name (use joins)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWy6Y.png)

Comment: Anyone here who can help me out with this query using joins please?

Comment: anyone here who could help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is hard to understand. Please check these recommendations: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic And these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have questions regarding the correct use of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Harry!

The way I would write this is as follows:

```
SELECT s.SName StudentName, 
       s.Gender Gender, 
       f.GName FatherName, 
       m.GName MotherName 
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Guardian f ON f.GuardianId = s.FatherId
INNER JOIN Guardian m ON m.GuardianId = s.MotherId
```

The inner join clause will retain only the students for which both guardians are filled in. If you would want to have the guardians as optional fields, you could replace the 'inner join' by 'left join'. In that case all the records of the 'left' table (for instance students, as this would be left of the join) will be displayed, even if there is no guardian linked to it.

More information on the inner join clause and other types of joins can be found on the page of w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped you out, please mark this answer as the accepted answer to your question.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for being thorough and explaining your answer :)

Comment: What does SO think about w3 schools these days?

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL that will give you what you want.

```
    SELECT 
      Student.SName AS StudentName,
      Student.Gender,
      Father.GName AS FatherName,
      Mother.GName AS MotherName 
    FROM Student
      LEFT JOIN Guardian AS Father ON Father.GuardianID = Student.FatherId
      LEFT JOIN Guardian AS Mother ON Mother.GuardianID = Student.MotherId
```

Comment: Dan Hawkins love u.

Comment: As a note, I used a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. In the example data you provided, there is a guardian name "tania" that does not exist in the Guardian table; at least not in your example. So, in this case, using an INNER JOIN would exclude the record for the student "abdullah" since there is not a relating guardian record. Using a LEFT JOIN would still give you the record for "abdullah"

Honestly, INNER vs LEFT is neither right or wrong. It all depends on what you are expecting to see in the result.